# Why refer to people as 'resource'?

Tags: management, human-resources

I hear this all the time.

> I'll see if I have a resource available.
>
> Perhaps an India resource can pick this up.
>
> All my resources are busy.

But what they mean is

> I'll see if anyone is available.
>
> Perhaps someone in our Indian office can work on this.
>
> All my supervisees are busy.

Why is 'resource' such a prevalent term for human being in the workplace? Is there any good reason?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20723/my-supervisor-treats-me-and-my-team-as-a-resource

Comment: This is better for English Stackexchange.  Note that some agencies, such as the CIA, also refer to people as "assets" (might be handy to know for asking your question over there).

Comment: I searched before posting but didn't find the other question. I'll leave this one (rather than delete it) because I think my title is easier to search for.

Comment: They shouldn't - its dehumanising. "Colleague" or "team member" is much better.

Comment: I absolutely hate this.  Had a team lead who would refer to me as a "resource" while I was in the same room.  I wanted to say "I'm right here, and I have a name."

Comment: What about Human Resources? HR for short, does it feel weird to you as well?

Comment: @Zikato I suppose it doesn't although HR people always treat me like a human being. What I don't like it when management refers to people in the room, on the call, copied on the email, etc as 'resource' rather than by their name.